# Using sakila database to find a movie by language

Tags: mysql

I'm new to the site and new in sql.
I use a sample database of sakila, I downloaded it from mysql website.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

I want to find a movie name by its language.
For example I want to find all the movies whose language is their original is English.

I have 2 tables that I use, the movie table and the language table, I JOIN this 2tables, and then return the names of the movies that are in English.

This is what I wrote down, but I can not understand why it does not work for me

```
Select title from film,language where original_language_id=language.language_id and language.name="ENGLISH";
```

I get an empty table, even though my movies are in English

Picture of the movie table, language table and query I wrote down:

[image] language table

[image] movie table

[image] query i wrote

I do not understand where the problem is, I think the problem is very small, but I can not find it

Comment: In the image of `movie` that you posted, the column `original_language_id` appears to be NULL.

Comment: @forpas Thanks for the help, I go to the name in the languages table. I do not use column with null. I join the tables according to the id of the language.

Comment: 'I do not use column with null' - yes you do where original_language_id=language.language_id

Comment: Thanks, you're right, my mistake, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd that anything came back with your original query as the `original_language_id` data is `NULL`, meaning no data has ever been set. Here is a SQL query that should give you what you need:

```
SELECT f.`title`
  FROM `film` f INNER JOIN `language` l ON f.`language_id` = l.`id`
 WHERE l.`name` = 'English';
```

If you're new to SQL, welcome! Do try to use the proper `JOIN` style as the method you used has not been actively used for 20+ years.

Cheers,